# Class with generic type as a return value

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I want to create function which returns **Object** with generic value. Are there solutions for achieve this?

```
protocol Protocol {}

class A1: Protocol {}
class A2: Protocol {}

class Test<T> {}

func function<T: Protocol>() -> Test<T> {
    return Test<A2>()
//    return Test<A1>()
}
```